# Networking 2 Virtual PC with one VPC as DHCP server

Tags: virtualization

My host OS is Win XP Professional.
The host has a real network connection via DSL and I created a second network connection using Microsoft Loopback Adapter. Internet connection sharing is enabled. The Microsoft Loopback adapter has a IP address of 192.168.0.1.

I have 1 Virtual PC which has Windows Server 2003. I have setup the network connection on this VPC to use Microsoft Loopback Adapter. I setup this VPC to be the Domain Controller , DNS Server and DHCP Server. I set this to a static IP address 192.168.0.2 (on the same subnet as the MS Loopback adapter)

I have a second Virtual PC which also has Windows Server 2003. The network connection on this VPC is set to "Local Only". I want this VPC to get its IP address from the 1st VPC on which I setup as a DHCP server.

What i want is the 2 VPC should be in a network with one of the VPC acting as the domain controller, DNS Server and DHCP server. The second VPC shoud get its IP address from the 1st VPC. It should be a part of the domain of the 1st VPC.

When i tried to make the second VPC get the IP address from the first VPC I am not succeeding. Can somebody post some suggestions on how to go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your responses.
I solved my problem. Here's what I did (this is similar to what both of you suggested)
On VPC-1 (which acts as the domain controller , DNS Server and DHCP Server) I setup the network settings in the VPC console to 2 network adapters a) MS lookup adapter b) Local Only. The ip address for the first network connection (in TCP/IP settings) is set to "Obtain IP address automatically"
The ip address for the second network connection is set to a static address 192.168.0.5, the DNS Server is also set to the same address (192.168.0.5)

On VPC-2 (the client computer) I have only 1 networ connection. The IP address of that in TCP/IP settings is set to "Obtain IP address automatically".

Doing this ensured that VPC-2 was getting its IP address from the DHCP Server (in VPC-1) but there was still one small issue. Running an nslookup command was giving this output -
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.0.5: Non-existent domain
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.5

I fixed this by creating a PTR record in the reverse lookup zone which points the address 192.168.0.5 to the server name.

I guess I can remove the MS loopback adapter and use NAT (haven't tried it yet). So in what kind of situation do we absolutely need to use the MS Loopback Adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is for your 1st VPC, setup 2 nic's.  One should NAT your physical machine adapter and the other should be a private adapter.  The 2nd VPC should have a NIC with using the Local Only network.  That way, the 2 VPC's are both talking to each other on the "local only" network

Answer (score 0):

For this configuration you don't actually need to enable to the loopback adapter or internet connection sharing on your Windows XP Host. This can all be completed through the Virtual PC GUI.

Modify your first Virtual 2003 server, such that it has two network adapters. Have adapter 1 be assigned to "Shared networking (NAT)" and the second configured as "Local only". Turn on this VM and verify that it can connect to the internet as well as configure the second network adapter with a static IP address. Configure the desired DHCP scope and verify the service is enabled and running.

Modify the second Virtual 2003 server, such that it has a single network adapter. Configure it to be "Local only" and turn on the virtual machine. As it boots, it should request and be assigned a DHCP address from the first server. If not, double check the configuration of the network adapter.